# Ajax Alert Response from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, response

Hopefully an easy question here. I actually used an example I found on SO but can't figure out why its not working. No errors in console or anything.

I have an ajax Post function I am using to pass data to a php script.

Its passing the data correct, but the response each time is coming back as an error alert. I can confirm that server side is getting the data and processing it correctly, just can't figure out why its never returning a success response.

Here is the Ajax:

```
    $(function () {
        $('#pseudoForm').on('click', '#submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "psu_output.php",
                data: $('#pseudoForm').serialize(),
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response.type == 'success') {
                        $('#messages').addClass('alert alert-success').text(response.message);
                    } else {
                        $('#messages').addClass('alert alert-danger').text(response.message);
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

And in my php script I used this:

```
<?php

$success = true;

if($success == true) {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'success', 'message' => 'YAY'));
} else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'message' => 'WHOOPS'));
}

die($output);
?>
```

Comment: At runtime, what does `response` actually contain?

Comment: Use `console.log(response)` to see the response.

Comment: try to echo the $output, instead of die()

Comment: @guyfawkes `die()` echoes its argument if it's a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `datatype: 'json'` should be `dataType: 'json'`. Javascript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. For others reading, I actually had to do 2 things:1) fix the typo and 2) put it above the rest of my php script. I had it below and it was not returning correctly. (Well it was sending the response but ajax didn't see it).

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you received the returned data as json but the content type is a simple string (text/html) so you need to `JSON.parse()` the received data first like so:

```
$(function () {
    $('#pseudoForm').on('click', '#submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "psu_output.php",
            data: $('#pseudoForm').serialize(),
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            if(response.type == 'success') {
                    $('#messages').addClass('alert alert-success').text(response.message);
            } else {
                    $('#messages').addClass('alert alert-danger').text(response.message);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The second option is to send json headers from php itself thus removing the need of parsing JSON in javascript. You can do that by using the following line of code **BEFORE ECHOING OR PRINTING ANYTHING ELSE FROM THE PHP SCRIPT**:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

and then

```
echo $output;
```

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` makes it parse it automatically. The problem is that he has a typo there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with JSON responses, you need to set the header so your browser and your JavaScript could interpret it correctly:

```
<?php

$success = true;

if ($success == true) {
    $output = json_encode(array(
        'type' => 'success',
        'message' => 'YAY'
    ));
} else {
    $output = json_encode(array(
        'type' => 'error',
        'message' => 'WHOOPS'
    ));
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $output;
```

Comment: You don't need this if you use `dataType: 'json'`. The problem is he has a typo there.

Comment: There is so much ways to solve it, yours is one of them, mine is one too.